# Unable to parse json with complex object (JSON.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I am unable to parse below json using Json.net library. I am confuse what to do in case object comes within object. 
I am using JSON.net library and able to get data except "list" object. Please help.

```
            @"{""status"":1, ""list"": 
                {""231784875"": 
                    {
                        ""item_id"":""231784875"",
                        ""title"":""ASP.Net Skill Test, ASP.Net quiz, ASP.Net Online Tests, Online Assessments,"",
                        ""url"":""http:\/\/www.techgig.com\/skilltest\/ASP-Net"",
                        ""time_updated"":""1351228692"",
                        ""time_added"":""1349344004"",
                        ""state"":""1""
                    }
                }
            ,""since"":1351228692,
            ""complete"":0
            }";
```

Please check my below codes

```
private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject o= JObject.Parse(results);
            JArray list = (JArray) o[o["list"]];
            //getting error 
        }
        myResponse.Close();
    }
```

Error description

```
Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: {
  "211384805": {
    "item_id": "211384805",
    "title": "Introduction | Developer Portal",
    "url": "https://developer.uidai.gov.in/site/node/19",
    "time_updated": "1351109730",
```

JSON Structure by API Provider

Below is Json Structure from API provider.

```
{
   "status":"1",            // 1=normal, 2=no changes since your provided 'since'
   "since":"1245626956',        // timestamp of this response
   "list":{
      "93817":{
         "item_id":"93817"          // unique id identifying the url
         "url":"http://url.com",
         "title":"Page Title",
         "time_updated":"1245626956",       // time the item was last added/changed
         "time_added":"1245626956",     // time item was added to list
         "tags":"comma,seperated,list",
         "state":"0",                       // 0=unread, 1=read
      },
      "935812":{
         "item_id":"935812"         // unique id identifying the url
         "url":"http://google.com",
         "title":"Google",
         "time_updated":"1245626956",       // time the item was last added/changed
         "time_added":"1245626956",     // time item was added to list
         "tags":"comma,seperated,list",
         "state":"1",                       // 0=unread, 1=read
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: when i have to deserialize json i use newtonsoft, and it's pretty easy http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: I am also using newtonsoft but not sure how to map anonymous object. If you see in error description  "211384805: is coming. I want to know how to handle this value. This value is dynamic and can change with every item.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that list is not an array. If so the json would look like this:

```
{"list":[
            {...}
        ]
}
```

You can try this:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray jArray;
if(o["list"].Type==JTokenType.Array)
{
    jArray = (JArray) o["list"];
}
```

Edit:
The use of "list" is confusing since it is still not a jsonarray
the new json is equivalent to:

```
public class List
{
    public 93817 { get; set; }
    public 935812 { get; set; }
}
```

You can try this:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var array = new JArray(jObject["list"].Values());
```

The string you provided is not valid Json by the way there were commas missing etc.

Comment: I just added structure which API provider is giving. Please advice.

Comment: Thanks Larsson. 

I appreciate your help. Let me try this first.